# How to maintain distance between bases in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am facing three problems right now and i want to get there answer seprately, First question had already been asked you can also answer that first....

```
import pygame, sys
from random import randint
pygame.init()
screen_size = (350,674)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(screen_size)
pygame.display.set_caption("First Game")

x_poss = randint(0,350)
y_poss = randint(0,675)
bird_width = 20
bird_height = 20
base_width = 50
base_height = 5
vel = 8

bases = []
spines = []


red = (255,0,0)

image_1 = pygame.image.load('bird2.png').convert_alpha()
image_2 = pygame.image.load('base.png').convert_alpha()
image_3 = pygame.image.load('base2.png').convert_alpha()
image_4 = pygame.image.load('enemy.png').convert_alpha()

run = True
num_bases = 5
num_spines = 5
is_game_over = False
grav = 1
velo = 2
j = 10

isJump = False
jumpCount = j
base = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,255,255), (randint(0,330), randint(0,675), base_width, base_height))

def jump():
    global jumpCount, y_poss
    for base in bases:
        if bird.colliderect(base):
            isJump = True
            if jumpCount >= -j:
                y_poss -= (jumpCount * abs(jumpCount)) * 0.5
                jumpCount -= 1
            else:
                jumpCount = j
                isJump = False

def draw_rect(color, x, y, base_width, base_height):
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, (x,y,base_width, base_height))

def game_over(x,y):
    game_over_font = pygame.font.Font('Omnibus.ttf',40)
    game_over_text = game_over_font.render('GAME OVER', True, (0,0,0))
    screen.blit(game_over_text, (x,y))



while len(bases) < 2*num_bases:
    rect = pygame.Rect(randint(0,330), randint(0,675), base_width, base_height)
    test_rect = rect.inflate(100, 100)
    if test_rect.collidelist(bases) < 0:
        bases.append(rect)

while len(spines) < num_spines:
    rect = pygame.Rect(randint(0,330), randint(0,675), 10, 10)
    if rect.collidelist(spines) < 0:
        spines.append(rect)

while run:
    pygame.time.delay(40)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    key = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if key[pygame.K_LEFT] and x_poss > vel - base_width:
        x_poss -= vel

    if key[pygame.K_q]:
        run = False
        sys.exit()

    if key[pygame.K_RIGHT] and x_poss < 350 - vel - base_width:
        x_poss += vel

    if not(isJump):
        if key[pygame.K_UP] and y_poss > vel:
            y_poss -= vel

        if key[pygame.K_DOWN] and y_poss < 670 - base_height - vel:
            y_poss += vel

        if key[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            isJump = True
    else:
        if jumpCount >= -10:
            y_poss -= (jumpCount * abs(jumpCount)) * 0.5
            jumpCount -= 1
        else:
            jumpCount = 10
            isJump = False

    bird = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,255,255), (x_poss, y_poss, bird_width, bird_height))
    spine = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,0,0), (300,440,10,10))

    screen.fill((255,255,255))

    draw_rect((255,255,255),x_poss, y_poss, base_width, base_height)
    screen.blit(image_1, bird)

    for spine in spines:
        screen.blit(image_4, spine)
        spine.x += velo
        if spine.x >= 355:
            spine.x = -15
        if spine.colliderect(bird):
            is_game_over = True
            break

    for base_1 in bases[:num_bases]:
        screen.blit(image_2, base_1)
    for base_2 in bases[num_bases:]:
        screen.blit(image_3, base_2)

    for i, base_1 in enumerate(bases[:num_bases]):
        if base.collidelist(bases[i+1:]) >= 0:
            bases.remove(base_1)
            bases.append(pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,255,255), (randint(0,330), randint(0,675), base_width, base_height)))
            screen.blit(image_2, base_1)

    for i, base_2 in enumerate(bases[num_bases:]):
        if base.collidelist(bases[i+1:]) >= 0:
            bases.remove(base_2)
            bases.append(pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,255,255), (randint(0,330), randint(0,675), base_width, base_height)))
            screen.blit(image_3, base_2)

    for base_1 in bases[:num_bases]:
        base_1.y += grav
        base_1.x += 0
        if base_1.x == -50:
            base_1.x = 360

        if base_1.y == 675:
            base_1.x = randint(0,315)
            base_1.y = randint(-10, 0)

    for base_2 in bases[num_bases:]:
        base_2.y += grav
        base_2.x += 0
        if base_2.x == 360:
            base_2.x = -50

        if base_2.y == 675:
            base_2.x = randint(0,315)
            base_2.y = randint(-10, 0)

    """for i, base in enumerate(bases):
        while i < len(bases):
            i += 1
            if bases[i+1].y - bases[i].y < 20:
                difference = bases[i+1].y - bases[i].y
                base.y + difference"""

    """for i, spine in enumerate(spines):
        i += 1
        if spines[i].y - spines[0].y < 20:
            spine.y + (spines[i].y - spine.y)"""

    if is_game_over:
        grav = 0
        velo = 0
        game_over(45, 336)

    jump()

    pygame.display.update()
```

2. Second problem, The distance between the bases is not maintained or equal....I want to write a if condition which will run through the 'bases' list and ensures that if the y-distance between two rect is less than 20 it will change its position to random x-cordinate and the y-distance will be 20......

*i want to implement the same concept in spines also*

```
for i, base in enumerate(bases):
        if base.y - base[i+1].y < 20:
            base.y + (bases[i+1].y - base.y)
```

[![See the image i want the distance between the bases to be eual to 20][1]][1]

**plz help me oout........**
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/THl3B.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is caused by the fact that you tried to get an element from `base` instead of `bases`

<s>`if base.y - base[i+1].y < 20:`</s>

```py
if base.y - bases[i+1].y < 20:
```

---

If you want to make sure that the objects have a certain distance, you need to enlarge the test area (rectangle) when placing the objects.

Use [`pygame.Rect.inflate`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.inflate) to grow or the rectangle size when you create the bases:

```py
while len(bases) < 2*num_bases:
    rect = pygame.Rect(randint(0,330), randint(0,675), width, height)

    test_rect = rect.inflate(0, 20)
    if test_rect.collidelist(bases) < 0:
        bases.append(rect)
```

And use it if the base needs to be repositioned at the top of the window:

```py
for base in bases:
    base.y += grav

    if base.top > 675:
        other_base = [b for b in bases if b != base]
        base.topleft = randint(0,360), 0
        while base.inflate(0, 40).collidelist(other_base) >= 0:
            base.x = randint(0,360)
```

---

However, I recommend to use [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) and [`pygame.sprite.Group`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group):

```py
class Base(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, img):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = img
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft = (x, y))
     
    def random_position(self, bases):
        bases.remove(self)
        self.rect.inflate_ip(0, 40)
        self.rect.topleft = randint(0,330), 0
        while pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, bases, False):
            self.rect.topleft = randint(0,330), 0
        self.rect.inflate_ip(0, -40)
        bases.add(self)

    def update(self, grav, bases):
        self.rect.y += grav
        if self.rect.top > 675:
            self.random_position(bases)

bases = pygame.sprite.Group()
while len(bases) < num_bases*2:
    img = image_2 if len(bases) < num_bases else image_3  
    base = Base(randint(0,330), randint(0,675), img)
    base.rect.inflate_ip(0, 40)
    if not pygame.sprite.spritecollide(base, bases, False):
        base.rect.inflate_ip(0, -40)
        bases.add(base)

while run:
    # [...]

    bases.update(grav, bases)

    # [...]

    screen.fill((255,255,255))
    bases.draw(screen)
```

Comment: Thanks for helping but when i try to implement it, it doesn't seems to be changed. I want the vertical distance between two bases to be fixed.And thanks for correcting me in the Error. How ever i am still trying to maintain the distance in the ~                                        
for i, base in enumerate(bases):
        while i < len(bases):
            i += 1
            if bases[i+1].y - bases[i].y < 20:
                difference = bases[i+1].y - bases[i].y
                base.y + difference~

Comment: @Azeem8869786 Is the `width` and `height` correct? Is it the size of the bases?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion actually i am working on the same project with two file both are same but i introduce minor changes in my test.py and if those changes working properly i implement them on g_g.py which is the final python file. Sorry for the confusion.I will edit the code.

Comment: OK  i'll try to use sprites. Well actually i am not so good in working with sprite so i might seek for help again.